# Compute haar measure of a subset of SU(n)

Tags: lie-groups, haar-measure

Let $$X_n=\{(a,b,c)\in (SU(n))^{3} : c=aba^{-1}b^{-1}\}\subset SU(n)$$
with $SU(n)$ munished with its standard metric (say, normalized so that the total volume is $1$).

Is there a good method to compute the "area" measure of this set? 
I'm not only looking for the solution to this single problem (though it does interest me), but to a general framework that would allows to consider many more cases (e.g.: other Lie groups, or other "group-like" equations- I don't know if there is a name for such a thing)...

I guess the whole Weyl theory around maximal tori and so on might be useful, but I don't really see how to apply it here.

I must precise also that I think there might be some technic that would consist on going to the Lie algebra, with gaussian measure on it with parameter $t\to \infty$. But this seems heavy and I'm not convincted this simplify the problem...

EDIT: At the view of the replies, I guess I should precise that the measure I want to compute is the one which is not trivial... that is, I don't want to compute the haar measure of my set. At each point of $(SU(n))^3$, I have the canonical $3n$-form $vol$ defined by the volume element. Set $V_x$ the space orthogonal to $X_n$ at $x$, and $n_x$ the unitary form spanning $V_x$ ( unitarity is well-defined by the metric on my Lie group). Then $vol$ can be written as $vol=n\wedge a$, for some $dim(X_n)$-form $a$ defined on $X_n$. What I want to compute is the integrale of $a$ over $X_n$. (here I have acted as if $X_n$ was a smooth submanifold, the singular part being "neglictable").

Comment: Let $V_r\subset V_{r+\epsilon}\subset G=SU(n)$ open $\mu(V_r)= r, \bigcap V_r= \{1\}, G = \bigcup V_r$,  $E(r,r,s) = \{ (a,b,c) \in G^3, a\in V_r,b\in V_r,c\in aba^{-1}b^{-1} V_s\}$ then $\nu(E(r,r,s))=\int_{a \in V_r} \int_{b \in V_r}\int_{d \in V_s} d\nu (a,b,aba^{-1}b^{-1}d) = \int_{a \in V_r} \int_{b \in V_r}\int_{d\in V_s} d\nu (a,b,d)=\mu(V_r)\mu(V_r)\mu(V_s) = r^2 s$ and your set is $X_n=\bigcap_{m \ge 1} (\bigcup_{k = 1}^\infty E(k,k,\frac{1}{m k^4}))$ so that $\nu(X_n)\le\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^\infty E(k,k,\frac{1}{m k^4})=\lim_{m \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{m k^2} = 0$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $m$ is Haar measure on a locally compact group $G$ and $S$ is as above then applying Tonelli's theorem to  $\chi_S$  shows that $$m\times m\times m(S)=\int_G\int_Gm(\{c\in G:c=aba^{-1}b^{-1}\})\,dadbb=\int_G\int_Gm(\{aba^{-1}b^{1-}\})\,dadb.$$

And if $G$ contains an infinite compact set then the measure of a singleton is ..., because... .

Comment: of course, but it's not $m^3(S)$ I want to compute....

Comment: Well I can't follow your description of what you do want to compute, sorry. (You define $V_n$ in terms of $X_n$ without saying what $X_n$ is...)

Comment: Title: "Compute haar measure of a subset of SU(n)". Edit: "I don't want to compute the haar measure of my set". Huh?

Comment: $X_n$ is litterally the first thing that is defined on my post (it's what you called $S$). Indeed my title is misleading, though from an infinitesimal point of view the "surface" measure really looks tike the haar measure (but the one on $(SU(n))^2$, not $(SU(n))^3$).

Comment: (would you replace $SU(n)$ by $\mathbb{R}^d$, my problem would turn out to be the computation of the area (2d-dimensional Lebesgue measure) of a $2d$-dimensional surface embedded into $\mathbb{R}^{3d}$)

Comment: @Isao Sorry about missing the definition of $X_n$. Your last comment does  clarify what you want here...